# Resized image is not showing

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to resize the original photo(corgi.png) to 100 x 100. I am able to to show the original photo by using this code: context.drawImage(image, 0, 0); but the resized photo (100x100) is not showing. What am I doing wr0ng?

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("demoCanvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

let image = new Image();
image.src = "corgi.png";
image.onload = () => {

  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

  let smallImageData = new ImageData(100,100);

  context.putImageData(smallImageData, 500, 0);
 
};
```

Comment: The image is not showing because you are drawing it 500 px to the right

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using `drawImage` and `putImageData` both here.

The [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) for `drawImage` is enough to get the required result:

```
drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
```

Using this, your code would look like:

```
let image = new Image();
image.src = "corgi.png";
image.onload = () => {
  context.drawImage(image, 500, 0, 100, 100);
};
```

---

***Note:** Make sure your canvas width is greater than `dx + dWidth`, i.e. 500 + 100 = 600. Otherwise your image will not be visible.*

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("demoCanvas");
canvas.width = 1000; // >=600
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. To answer your question, we have to create our own algorithm. We are not supposed to use the built in Canvas API. the html used for the canvas side is   <canvas id="demoCanvas" width="1600" height="1280"></canvas>. any suggestions to show both images?